# SWF file displayed but xml data not loading into the swf embedded in aspx page

Tags: xml, file, external, asp.net, swfobject

the flash map calls the xml external file which contains data
the map shows in firefox and works a treat but wont show any of the xml data
Help

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it not displaying in IE is due to the embed code, in your index.aspx page, make sure that the embed code matches, currently it doesn't:

```
  <param name="movie" value="Index.aspx_files/FlashMap.swf">  

  <param name="quality" value="high">

   <param name="flashvars" value="file=/Controls/Home/menuworld.xml">  

   <embed src="Index.aspx_files/FlashMap.swf" quality="high" flashvars="file=/Controls/Home/menuworld.xml" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="835" height="235">
```

The paths **"VALUE"** need to match, FIREFOX used the src in the embed tag, IE uses the value in the param tag, that’s why it didnt work in IE

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use a proxy for your xml data. It will not display if it comes from an outside domain due to a "sandbox security violation".